# Build Gradle Eterno

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Não achei algo parecido.
Quando tento executar uns projetos de um livro ele fica assim:

> "Gradle: Resolve dependencies: 'app:_debugCompile'"

E não compila por nada. Alterei o meu arquivo Gradle para as versões que tenho.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.exemplo.material"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

E ainda sim fica "compilando" direto e não dá erro, fica meio travado.
Não sei o que fazer.

Segue abaixo a imagem.
[image: Erro]

Answer (score 1):

o meu estava assim no meu caso, era um erro no arquivo xml onde eu tinha um cardview
fui no menu File, Settings
Build,Execution,Deployment> Build Tools> Gradle e habilitei o opção Offline work, dei um Clean Project e depois Rebuild Project e ele logo acusou o erro.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Tentarei fazer dessa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Estava com o mesmo problema, então resolvi ajudar, para aumentar a velocidade de Build do Gradle, modifique as suas configurações e scripts da seguinte maneira:

1 - Clique em File > Settings > Gradle > e Modifique como está abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> - Selecione a opção Offline work e clique OK

---

2 - Clique em File > Settings > Compiler > e Modifique como está abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> - Selecione as quatro opções acima "Compile, Make, Sync, Configure" e coloque em `Command-line Options: --offline` e clique OK

---

3 - modifique o seguinte script **build.gradle(Module:app)** - adicione **dexOptions**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
       ...
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    }
```

Adicione este trecho:

```
    dexOptions {
                    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
}
```

---

4 - modifique o seguinte script **gradle.properties(Project Properties)**:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true


# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Adicione este trecho:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Se aparecer algum aviso lá em cima, clique em `Try Again...` ou `Sync Now`, e veja o resultado.

---

**Dica:** Caso seu Android Studio estiver demorando muito para iniciar, recomendo também ver este [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131525/como-aumentar-a-mem%C3%B3ria-da-ide-android-studio/) sobre como aumentar a memoria da IDE.

---

Espero ter ajudado. comigo funcionou, o **Gradle** está mais rápido.