# Como aumentar a memória da IDE Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Ultimamente tenho desenvolvido para Android, e tenho notado que a IDE Android Studio demora muito para carregar e iniciar.

Gostaria então de saber, como aumentar a memoria da IDE Android Studio?

Para iniciar a IDE mais rapidamente e consequentemente desenvolver mais rápido...

Answer (score 7):

Não é aconselhável editar qualquer arquivo na pasta de instalação do Android Studio, até porque, qualquer alteração será perdida quando houver uma actualização da IDE.

A forma correcta é as definições(atributos) alterados serem colocados em arquivos criados numa pasta localizada na pasta do seu *profile*(`%USERPROFILE%\`).

O [caminho dessa pasta](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration) depende da versão da IDE instalada.

A partir da versão 2.0 deixa de ser necessário fazer essas alterações manualmente.

O Android Studio disponibiliza no menu **Help** a opção **Edit Custom VM Options**, que criará automaticamente o arquivo, na localização certa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo é aberto numa aba do editor de forma a poder ser editado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O atributo referente à quantidade de memória que o Android Studio usa é o `-Xmx1280m`, neste caso 1280Mb.

<sub>Fonte: [Configuring Android Studio: IDE & VM Options, JDK, etc.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration)</sub>

Mais info em [Configure Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html).

Answer (score 5):

### Configurando a memória adequadamente para a IDE Android Studio

Achei a resposta em um [artigo](http://imasters.com.br/mobile/android/ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-android-lento-demorado-chato-aqui-nao), e peguei como base para minha resposta e resolvi compartilhar aqui no SOpt.

O Android Studio, por default(padrão), vem configurado com pouca memória, e por isso ele fica tão lento para iniciar, carregar, desenvolver e fazer deploy.

O segredo aqui é usar um PC com no mínimo 4GB de RAM e colocar  no mínimo 2GB para o Android Studio.

### Como fazer?

Na pasta de instalação, tem uma pasta chamada de bin(ex: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`) e, dentro dela, há 2 arquivos: `studio.exe.vmoptions` e `studio64.exe.vmoptions`. Se você usa pc 32 bits, altere o `studio.exe.vmoptions`. Se usa 64 bits, altere o outro. Configure adequadamente o xmx, xms , permsize, cachesize e outras internas.

### ** Aviso Importante **

> Antes de editar os arquivos `studio.exe.vmoptions` e
>   `studio64.exe.vmoptions`, saiba que eles são arquivos protegidos,
>   então, não basta somente editar e salvar, porque dará erro, o Android
>   Studio não permite a edição e o salvar do arquivo direto na pasta bin,
>   então, o que você vai fazer é clicar com o botão direito em cima do
>   arquivo, selecionar abrir com o bloco de notas, editar o arquivo e na
>   hora de salvar, você salva o arquivo assim -> Nome:
>   `studio.exe.vmoptions`, Tipo: `Todos os arquivos(*)` e salve em sua
>   `área de trabalho` e depois de ter salvo, é ai que você copia este
>   novo arquivo que está na sua área de trabalho e cola na pasta bin e
>   substitui o arquivo anterior, aquele procedimento usual - onde o
>   windows irá perguntar  `Deseja substituir o arquivo antigo pelo novo`
>   e você clica em `Sim, desejo substituir o arquivo antigo pelo novo` e
>   agora tudo está ok, você fez a atualização do arquivo por
>   substituição!

Veja o arquivo `studio.exe.vmoptions` abaixo, provavelmente ele deve estar com valores muito baixos, assim:

```
#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

Modifique o seguinte trecho:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=150
```

Depois de ter modificado o trecho acima, salve o arquivo em sua `área de trabalho`, dessa maneira:

- Nome: `studio.exe.vmoptions`
- Tipo: `Todos os arquivos(*)`

Depois de ter salvo, é ai que você copia este novo arquivo que está na sua área de trabalho e cola na pasta bin e substitui o arquivo pelo anterior.

---

Veja o arquivo `studio64.exe.vmoptions` abaixo, provavelmente ele deve estar com valores muito baixos, assim:

```
#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

Modifique o seguinte trecho:

```
 -Xms256m
 -Xmx2048m
 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=150
```

Depois de ter modificado o trecho acima, salve o arquivo em sua `área de trabalho`, dessa maneira:

- Nome: `studio64.exe.vmoptions`
- Tipo: `Todos os arquivos(*)`

Depois de ter salvo, é ai que você copia este novo arquivo que está na sua área de trabalho e cola na pasta bin e substitui o arquivo pelo anterior.

---

Espero ter ajudado, basta agora atualizar os arquivos e iniciar a IDE Android Studio, e você verá que o Android Studio está iniciando muito mais rápido!

Answer (score 2):

A partir do Android Studio 3.5 é possível configurar a quantidade de memória alocada para a IDE diretamente nas configurações da mesma.

Caminho:

Menu File => Settings => Appearance & Behavior => System Settings => Memory Settings.

Selecione a quantidade que deseja utilizar, aplique e reinicie a IDE para as alterações terem efeito e está tudo OK.

O print mostra as quantidades de memória disponíveis.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte:

Android Developers

What’s new in Android Studio 3.5

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJ3K90FpQ6A&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_w6fodMGrA1_tsI3pqPbqa&index=3&t=0s

Answer (score 1):

Esta solução funcionou pra mim, mas o arquivo na versão 3.1 do android studio agora se chama `studio64.exe` e o seu conteúdo está assim:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-da
```

Tendo sindo modificados para estes valores:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=150
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-da
```

Percebi que o tempo de carregamento de um projeto caiu pela metade. Não fiz medições co relação à execução ainda.